# In ul i have 30 list with 5 headers. On scroll i want to make the header sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an ul i have some 30 list with 5 headers. On scroll i want to make the header sticky when it reach the container top using jquery(without css property position:fixed).

```css
#category{
  width:150px;
  height:140px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#category ul li{
  height:20px;
  width:108px;
  border:none;
  font-size:13px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#header{
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size:15px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="category">
<ul>
<li id="header" >Fruits</li>
<li>Mango</li>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Banana</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li id="header" >Vegitable</li>
<li>Carrot</li>
<li>Potato</li>
<li>Onion</li>
<li>Tomato</li>
<li id="header" >Flowers</li>
<li>Rose</li>
<li>Lily</li>
<li>Sunflower</li>
<li>Marrygold</li>
<li id="header" >Birds</li>
<li>Peacock</li>
<li>Parrot</li>
<li>Pigeon</li>
<li>Cock</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: id's must be unique, instead use a class for sharing object.

Comment: @iHasCodeForU yes id has to unique. While posting i have'nt noticed it.

Comment: when will you switch a sticky header to another? Also, position:fixed is a good solution for sticking, otherwise you have to change margin-top all the time while scrolling.

Comment: @troy when it will reach the top of container. Yes position fixed is good solution but in some cases the container will have horizontal scroll and dragable property. In these cases its bit problematic.